# Is there a simple way to add a header to each View in a ViewSet?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using a simple TodoViewSet and want to add an extra header to each view in the set. Is there a simple way to do this?

```py
class TodoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TodoModel.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = serializers.TodoSerializer

    # eg extra_header = "My-Header: Foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `default_response_headers` property:

```
class TodoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TodoModel.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = serializers.TodoSerializer

    @property
    def default_response_headers(self):
        headers = viewsets.ModelViewSet.default_response_headers.fget(self)
        headers['My-Header'] = 'Foo'
        return headers
```